# How to write an Excel sheet to a tab separated .txt file with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I've got a program that's converting files from an Excel spreadsheet into a csv. However, I just realized that for one of the other things I'm working on, I need them to be tab separated .txt files.  How can I either convert what it's kicking out, or change it to do tab separated instead?

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('S:\\Digitization\\Metadata\\MS038_Civitan.xlsx', data_only = True)
sh1 = wb["MODS"]
with open('S:\\Digitization\\Metadata\\tools\\CSVs\\MODS.csv', 'wb') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh1.rows:
        out_val_list = list()
        for cell in r:
            out_val = cell.value
            if out_val == 0:
                out_val = ""
            out_val_list.append(out_val)
        c.writerow(out_val_list)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: Why is data "kicked out"?

Comment: My program creates a comma separated file from an Excel sheet.  I need a tab separated .txt file, instead.  How?

Comment: kicked out = output (slang)

Comment: So explain the "kicked out" data because the rest is simple enough and probably a dupe

Comment: The data that's being output is csv.  I need it to be a tab separated .txt instead.

Comment: Then your slang is off. "Kicked out" means, at least to me, that it's discarded

Comment: I found a solution thanks to Kapil.  Thank you for attempting to answer and downvoting other answers though.

Comment: Thank you for asking a dupe and assuming that I downvoted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose your delimiter like this

`csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')`

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: This worked.  I didn't realize csv.writer could write things to txt, but it does just fine.  Thank you!